# how to redirect from servlet to jsp using ajax instead of request dispatcher

Tags: javascript, java, ajax

```
<button type="submit" name ="ajax1" id="ajax1" onClick="return SaveAdminMessage();"><b>SEND</b></button>
```

while clicking above button to save the data that we enter and refresh the list that display the entered data.

```
function SaveAdminMessage() {
                alert("Please enter Your Message..!");

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: 'adminchatServlet',                   
                    success: alert("success ajax");
                });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing after successful call of ajax that you are making , you can right below code

```
if (success) {
 var pageToRedirectUrl = "success.jsp"; //URL of your page
 window.location.href = pageToRedirectUrl ;
}
```

Above code will allow you to redirect to another page after successfully executing ajax call.

Comment: when i write $.ajax()  inside function SaveAdminMessage(), button is not working properly and can't enter into the above function.Is that any jar file is needed ??

Comment: @Ayaan you dont need jar to execute javascript because it is at client side. Button is not working because you have wrong syntax or method.  you need jquery.js in case of if you are using jquery. Please go through basics about javascript and how it works .